# How to update array of drag & drop of Angular material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

I was trying the drag and drop of Angular material where I made the array as array of JSON.
The problem is I want to update the `pos` key (of the JSON) with the value of `event.currentIndex`
and modify the pos of other values also.

**component.ts**

```
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

temp: number;

movies = [
    {name: 'Episode I - The Phantom Menace', pos: 0},
    {name:'Episode II - Attack of the Clones', pos: 1},
    {name: 'Episode III - Revenge of the Sith', pos: 2},
    {name: 'Episode IV - A New Hope', pos: 3}
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    console.log(this.movies[event.currentIndex]);
    console.log(this.movies);
    this.temp = event.previousIndex;
    event.previousIndex = event.currentIndex;
    event.currentIndex = this.temp;
    this.movies[event.currentIndex].pos = event.currentIndex;
    this.movies[event.previousIndex].pos = event.previousIndex;
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies;" cdkDrag>
        {{movie.name}} {{movie.pos}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Initial list**

[image: Initial]

**After swapping**

[image: swapping]

This type of scenario is arising when I try to drag either the 1st or last value.

What change do I require in my code?

Comment: Avishek, the function `moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);` yet reorder the array, you needn't use the rest of code (if you're curious just see the code in github: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts

Answer (score 0):

as Avishek mentioned (leave only that code `moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);`), moveItemInArray is just sorting an array.
One easy way when you ready to save changes you may loop through your collection and update position according to index of item in array.

```
for( let i = 0; i < this.movies.length; i ++){
        this.movies[i].position = i
      }
```